# PyTorch: two binary masks union?

Tags: pytorch

I have two binary masks of shape `(batch_size, width, heigh)` that I want to create a binary mask which indicates the union of elements between the two.

To find the intersection, I can use `torch.where(A == B, 1, 0)`, but how can I find the union?

Comment: your intersection is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with binary masks, you should use logical operations such as:
[`logical_or()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.logical_or), [`logical_and()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.logical_and).

The intersection is then the binary mask:

```py
intersection = A.logical_and(B)
```

and the union is:

```py
union = A.logical_or(B)
```

---

BTW,
I'll leave it to you as an exercise to check why the intersection you computed (`A == B`) is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and if I think correctly, it is because `A==B` also includes zeros in it right?

Comment: @AerysS correct! `A==B` is the union of `intersect(A, B)` and `intersect(~A, ~B)`